# Can a neural network be used to optimize an objective cost function?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

I have been reading into Neural Networks with the aim of using them to optimize a multi objective cost function (aka finding Pareto fronts) which takes a long time to call.

The inputs are constrained to within a certain range of real numbers. Is the ONLY way a NN can help with this task is to come up with a computationally faster function to call to find an optimal solution or is there something more clever that I can do?

For example, can I teach the system using reverse data such that the objective function's output is my NN input and vice versa and try values of object output for a maxima/minima?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with your proposed approach:

- Neural Networks perform [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) - meaning that you will need existing examples of valid input-ouput pairs. In your case you will need several instances of input variables + correct values of your objective function to start training your network. But you just mentioned that your objective function takes a long time to call. So you have a "chicken and egg" problem.
- Second, even if you did have these values provided by some sort of oracle, training a neural network is itself a [difficult optimization problem](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/BR93.pdf). So you would simply be moving the difficulty of your optimization from the function call to the training of the neural net.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can search for **function approximation using neural network**. Where you try to treat the function to be approximated as a black box, feed input and collect output. Then use these data to train a NN, which is more "transparent" and can be optimized.